# How to generate list of *all* available commands and functions?

Tags: linux, bash, command, autocomplete

In Linux (I am using CentOS 7), there is a built in functionality to view all runnable commands. The command is run by pressing tab twice in the console followed by the prompt:

```
Display all 1130 possibilities? (y or n)
```

Pressing `y` outputs a huge list of commands to the console.

Is there a way to capture this output in a file?

Or is this list already stored locally? If so, how can I access this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I chose was to run the command:

```
$ compgen -A function -abck | sort -u >> cmds.txt
```

which appends all runnable commands, functions and aliases to a text file `cmds.txt`

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948008/linux-command-to-list-all-available-commands-and-aliases

Edit: added `sort -u` to command to remove duplicates as suggested by glenn jackman

Comment: `<pedantry>`It's actually appending, not writing.`</pedantry>`

Answer (score 4):

It seems `compgen` outputs duplicates: perhaps programs that appear in multiple locations in your PATH:

autocomplete says:

```
$ [tab][tab]
Display all 2328 possibilities? (y or n)
```

compgen says:

```
$ compgen -A function -abck | wc -l
2647
$ compgen -A function -abck | sort -u | wc -l
2328
```

I don't know if this is important for you.